# Given diagonals, lower base, and height, find the legs and upper base of isosceles trapezoid

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given an the height, base, and diagonals of an isosceles trapezoid, how am I to find the upper base and the legs?

I know I can find the area of the triangles made by the diagonals, but how is that helpful? Do I have to use trigonometry (law of sines or cosines)?

Comment: are you looking for algebraic or geometric construction?

Comment: @gt6989b Preferably geometric. But either is fine, I just want to see how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by drawing a sketch of the situation. Below is a crude image, but it will do for our purposes.

[image: sketch of isosceles trapezoid]

We know that $DX = \sqrt{d^{2} - x^{2}}$ by Pythagoras. Therefore, we have that $XC = b_{2} - DX = b_{2} - \sqrt{d^{2} - x^{2}}.$

Since $ABCD$ is isosceles, we have that $AB = b_{2} - 2XC = \boxed{2\sqrt{d^{2} - x^{2}} - b_{2}}.$

For the legs, use Pythagoras once again. Each leg has length
$$BC = \sqrt{x^{2} + \left(b_{2} - \sqrt{d^{2} - x^{2}}\right)^{2}}$$
$$= \sqrt{x^{2} + b_{2}^{2} - 2b_{2}\sqrt{d^{2} - x^{2}} + d^{2} - x^{2}}$$
$$\boxed{\sqrt{b_{2}^{2} - 2b_{2}\sqrt{d^{2} - x^{2}} + d^{2}}}.$$

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem; glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need geometric construction.

1. Starting from the lower base $AB$, draw the perpendicular upwards (with length of the height) at point $B$, say $BC$.
2. Then draw another perpendicular to $BC$ at point $C$, call this line $\ell$.
3. Now draw a circle $C_A$ from point $A$ with radius of the diagonal, and from $B$ - another circle $C_B$ with the same radius (both diagonals should have the same length since this is an isosceles trapezoid).
4. Each of $C_A$ and $C_B$ should intersect $\ell$ in two points. Call the right intersection of $C_A$ and $\ell$ as $K$, and the left intersection of $C_B$ and $\ell$ - as $D$.
5. You are looking for the trapezoid $ABKD$.